how to automatically align arabic text in R-Markdown document and tables
I'm currently working on a bilingual Arabic and English report using xelatex engine. I've included these in my R-Markdown YAML header so that arabic letters combine properly to create a word.
---
output: 
  pdf_document:
    latex_engine: xelatex
geometry: margin=1.7cm
params:
  branch: ""
  month: "May"
  year: "2024"
header-includes:
- \usepackage{pdflscape}
- \newcommand{\blandscape}{\begin{landscape}}
- \newcommand{\elandscape}{\end{landscape}}
- \usepackage{longtable}
- \usepackage{booktabs}
- \usepackage{hyperref}
- \usepackage{fontspec}
- \newfontfamily{\defaultfont}{Amiri}
- \newfontfamily{\latinfont}{Amiri}
- \newfontfamily{\arabicfont}[Script=Arabic,Scale=MatchLowercase]{Amiri}
- \usepackage[Latin, Arabic]{ucharclasses}
- \setDefaultTransitions{\defaultfont}{}
- \setTransitionsForLatin{\latinfont}{}
- \setTransitionsForArabics{\arabicfont}{}
---

However, the problem is that arabic words go from left to right just as in english, but should go right to left. This happens throughout the document, in my kableExtra tables as shown here, and the arabic titles for my ggplot2 do not render at all even though they are supported when run in R. I've also created some reproducible examples to be used for the tables and ggplot2 graphs.
For reference the arabic text should read like so الكل / الستيلات and الكل / تيكا in the tables.
library(showtext)
library(tidyverse)
library(readxl)
library(openxlsx)
library(tinytex)
library(kableExtra)
library(scales)
library(ggpubr)
showtext_auto()
knitr::opts_chunk$set(
    echo = FALSE,
    message = FALSE,
    warning = FALSE,
    error = FALSE
)

Sales <- structure(list(Product = c("ALUMACER / 0LA12NH - LISTELO ALUMINIO 12x12  mm NEGRO MATE LACADO 2,6 ml", 
"ALUMACER /0AL08NH - PERFIL ALUMINIO \"L\" 08  MM. NEGRO LACADO MATE 2,6 ML", 
"Alumacer/ 000CRU1 - CRUCETAS PVC 1 mm (كيس/ 300)", "Alumacer/ 000CRU3 - CRUCETAS PVC 3 mm (300/كيس)", 
"Alumacer/ 000CRU5 - CRUCETAS PVC 5 mm (كيس/300)", "Alumacer/ 0LA12PBLISTELO ALUMINIO 12x12 mm  PLATA BRILLO 2,6 ml", 
"Alumacer/0001CNK - CUÑAS NIVELACIÓN (كيس 100)", "Alumacer/001CRA2 - SEPARADORES NIVELACIÓN  ESTÁNDAR 2 mm (100/كيس)", 
"Alumacer/01CRA05 - SEPARADORES NIVELACIÓN  ESTÁNDAR 0,5 mm (كيس 100)", 
"Alumacer/01CRA15 - SEPARADORES NIVELACIÓN  ESTÁNDAR 1,5 mm(كيس 100)", 
"Alumacer/01CRA2G - SEPARADORES NIVELACIÓN ESTÁNDAR 2 mm XL (100 /كيس)", 
"Total", "Xtreme - SuperCol  PISCINAS", "Xtreme - SuperCol C2TES1", 
"Xtreme - SuperCol C2TES2", "Xtreme - XtraCol  C1TE", "Xtreme - XtraCol  C2TE", 
"لاصق GERMA-C1", "لاصق GERMA-Glue", "متين GERMA-C1TE", 
"متين GERMA-C2TE", "Total"), `Qty Sold.x` = c(5, 0, 6, 0, 
2, 2, 4, 17, 4, 0, 0, 40, 427, 4823, 1349, 7481, 11764, 1422, 
1584, 11890, 8314, 49054), `Qty Sold.y` = c(0, 3, 0, 3, 0, 0, 
2, 0, 0, 5, 10, 23, 18, 1656, 598, 803, 5199, 316, 588, 12566, 
2965, 24709), Diff1 = c("", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", 
"", "\\textcolor[HTML]{228B22}{17}", "", "", "", "", "", "", 
"", "", "", "\\textcolor[HTML]{228B22}{24345}")), row.names = c(NA, 
-22L), class = "data.frame")

Sales_qty2 <- structure(list(Product = c("Total", "Total", "Total", "Total", 
"Total", "Total"), Date = c("May", "April", "May", "April", "May", 
"April"), Value = c(37665, 23705, 3611, 564, 7778, 440), Region = c("East", 
"East", "Central", "Central", "West", "West")), row.names = c(NA, 
-6L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))

# Table Code Chunk

final_kable <- Sales %>% select("Product","Qty Sold.x","Qty Sold.y","Diff1") %>% knitr::kable(escape = FALSE,"latex", booktabs = T, longtable = T, align = c("l","r","r","r"), col.names = c("Product","Qty Sold","Qty Sold"," ")) %>%
  
  kableExtra::kable_styling(latex_options = c("scale_down"),position = "left", full_width = F) %>%
  kableExtra::kable_styling(font_size = 8.5) %>%
  
  kableExtra::row_spec(12, bold = T) %>%
  kableExtra::row_spec(22, bold = T) %>%

  kableExtra::pack_rows(group_label = "الكل / الستيلات", start_row = 1, end_row = 12) %>%
  kableExtra::pack_rows(group_label = "الكل / تيكا", start_row = 13, end_row = 22) %>%
  kableExtra::add_header_above(c(" " = 1, "May 2024" = 1, "Apr 2024" = 1, "Diff." = 1))

final_kable

# ggplot2 Code Chunk

ggplot(data = Sales_qty2, aes(x = Region, y = Value, fill = Date, label = Value)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = "dodge") +
  ggtitle("الكل / تيكا") +
  theme(legend.position = "right",
        plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5),
        axis.ticks.y = element_blank(),
        axis.ticks.x = element_blank(),
        axis.text.y = element_blank(),
        axis.text.x = element_text(size = 12),
        panel.background = element_rect(fill = "white"),
        plot.background = element_rect(fill = "white")) +
  labs(x = NULL, y = "Qty Sold") +
  geom_text(aes(label = Value), position = position_dodge(width = 1), vjust = -0.2, size = 3)

I've seen these StackOverflow questions here and here as well, but i could not add the lua filter mentioned and did not know if it also worked for the problems that I'm experiencing.

When I do that, all text (even english) is rtl and the arabic words in my kableExtra tables still read ltr @tarleb

from the pandoc MANUAL: "For bidirectional documents, native pandoc spans and divs with the dir attribute (value rtl or ltr) can be used to override the base direction in some output formats." So try e.g. [hello world]{dir=rtl}

Add the keep_tex: true option to the output format, and look at the .tex file that is produced.  Figure out how to modify that file to get the text you want.  If you know LaTeX and have worked with Arabic in it before, that should be easy.  If not, you're going to need LaTeX help -- see tex.stackexchange.com.  Once you have the .tex file corrected, you can use the strings it contains in your tables, and produce the table with escape = FALSE, so those strings are transmitted as-is to the final output.  If this all works, please post an answer to your question for others to see.

For an old description of the LaTeX approach, see here:  https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/12347
